# how to change the state of one statefulwidget from another in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a stateful widget which is conditionally rendering two childs inside stack, and i want to change the condition of the rending from a third child . any idea ?

Parent code :

```
  class MapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Body()
    );
  }
}

class Body extends StatefulWidget { 
  final String showScreen;
  
  const Body({
    Key key, 
    this.showScreen="post",
  }) : super(key:key);

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  
  
  Widget _conditionedWidget(){
  if(this.widget.showScreen=="map"){
   return MapScreen();
 }else if(this.widget.showScreen == "post"){
   return PostScreen();
 }
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      DrawerScreen(),
      _conditionedWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

child code

```
class DrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerScreenState createState() => _DrawerScreenState();
}

class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color:kPrimaryColor,
      padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:70),  
      child:Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(width:20.0),
              CircleAvatar(),
              SizedBox(width:10.0),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Biswas Sampad',style:TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  )),
                  Text('@biswassampad',style:TextStyle(
                    color:Colors.grey[200],
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                  ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical:20),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:30),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.style, name:'Explore',action:(){
                      print('showing maop');
                }),
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.tag_faces, name:'Profile',action:(){
                      print('showing profile');
                }),
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.people, name:'People',action:(){
                      print('showing People');
                }),
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.speaker_notes, name:'Messages',action:(){
                      print('showing messages');
                }),
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.notifications, name:'Notifications',action:(){
                      print('showing Notifications');
                }),
                MenuButton(icon:Icons.satellite,name:'Settings',action:(){
                      print('showing settings');
                })
              ],
            ),
          ),
          LogoutSection()
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

So basically i want to change the showScreen value of the parent widget from DrawerScreen>MenuButton>action ?

any idea how to do it !! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **Function** in "DrawerScreen" widget like this :

write this code into the header of the class :

```
final Function onChangeState = Function();
DrawerScreen({@rquired onChangeState});
```

and in MenuButton call  **onChangeState** function , like this:

```
 MenuButton(icon:Icons.satellite,name:'Settings',action:(){
                      widget.onChangeState("Settings");
                })
```

and change old code in **Body** widget to :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
      DrawerScreen(onChangeState : (newState){
       setState(){
          this.widget.showScreen = newState;
         };
       }),
      _conditionedWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: let me try this approach