# How to call Void() function in another Stateful widget

Tags: flutter

I want to call the void play() method in another stateful widget

**main.dart**

```
    import 'dart:io';
import 'package:audioplayer/audioplayer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:record_mp3/record_mp3.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'regitration.dart';
import 'voiceCreate.dart';
import 'stopwatch.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return MyApp();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Sign up'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return StopWatch();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Sign in'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginScreen();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                    // add sign in page
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return MyHomePage();
                }),
              );
            },
            // Add your onPressed code here!

            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent.shade700,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Myvo'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent.shade700,
          ),
          body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              startRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              pauseRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              stopRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    statusText,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onTap: () {
                    play();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 50,
                    child: isComplete && recordFilePath != null
                        ? Text(
                            "play",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    if (!await Permission.microphone.isGranted) {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.microphone.request();
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  void startRecord() async {
    bool hasPermission = await checkPermission();
    if (hasPermission) {
      statusText = "Recording...";
      recordFilePath = await getFilePath();
      isComplete = false;
      RecordMp3.instance.start(recordFilePath, (type) {
        statusText = "Record error--->$type";
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      statusText = "No microphone permission";
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void pauseRecord() {
    if (RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.PAUSE) {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "Recording...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    } else {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.pause();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "Recording pause...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  void stopRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.stop();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "Record complete";
      isComplete = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void resumeRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "Recording...";
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  String recordFilePath; //maybe**strong text** this need to take

  void play() {
    if (recordFilePath != null && File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      audioPlayer.play(recordFilePath, isLocal: true);
    }
  }

  int i = 0;

  Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    Directory storageDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String sdPath = storageDirectory.path + "/record";
    var d = Directory(sdPath);
    if (!d.existsSync()) {
      d.createSync(recursive: true);
    }
    return sdPath + "/test_${i++}.mp3";
  }
}
```

**voiceCreate.dart**
I want to call here when `onPressed`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _isRecording = false;

MyHomePage.play()**//getting error here** 

  _startRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
    });
  }

  _stopRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 70,
                onPressed: () => _startRecording(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 70,
                onPressed: () => _stopRecording(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () => `MyHomePage(title: "My title", play: this.play()),`**// getting error here**
              ),
```

already called the **starRecording** and **stopRecording**

all three functions are not working when onPressed, these are startRecording, stopRecording and play. these function are working okay in main.dart but not in voiceCreate.dart

Comment: I've answered something like this before, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62869389/10498374)

Answer (score 0):

Dart functions are first-class, that means you can pass them around like a variable. Have a `VoidCallback` member on your widget class.

```
MyHomePage(this.playCallback, {Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final VoidCallback playCallback;
```

You can pass it in the constructor.

```
child: MyHomePage(play)
```

Then you can reach it in your state object.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
    ...

    onPressed: widget.playCallback

    ...    
}
```

**Warning**

This is not a recommended way to achieve this. Widgets must contain zero business logic if possible. Little hacks like this answer will make your code very complex than it should be. Consider reading [state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 3.0**

As per the full code you have shown, here is the solution as per your code only. I am sure it will clear out some confusions for you.

- Passing the `play()` correctly to your `MyHomePage` from `main.dart` in your `FloatingActionButton`. I am not using full code of `main.dart`, but specifically your part, where you are moving to the `MyHomePage`

**main.dart**

```
           floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  // you need to pass two positional arguments
                  // since your MyHomePage accepts two arguments
                  // one is your title and one is your function
                  return MyHomePage(title: "My Title", play: play);
                }),
              );
            }
```

- Secondly, use your method to be passed in your `MyHomePage` constructor. This will remain as is. Just look at the last line of the code here, and see how are we using the passed `play()` method from your `main.dart`

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  // accepting the method in the constructor
  // so you can pass it with the title from your main.dart
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.play}) : super(key: key);
  
  final String title;
  final Function play; // this is the function
  
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

Now how to use that in your Class

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _isRecording = false;

  _startRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
    });
  }

  _stopRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 70,
                onPressed: () => _startRecording(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 70,
                onPressed: () => _stopRecording(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
                  color: Colors.black,
                  onPressed: () => widget.play() // call like this
              )
```

**Note:** Please look at the comments in my code as well

Now check if that works for you. This should probably fix your problem.

Comment: Hey @LinuMariya, no no, you have done it wrong. Let me show you how to do it as per your new code. And you update me then

Comment: @LinuMariya I have edited the code. This is whole new answer as per the errors you were getting. Let me know, it is under section **Answer 2.0**

Comment: got confused with main.dart, sharing full view of main.dart, please check and help

Comment: @LinuMariya please check the new answer, follow the answer right from the start **Answer 3.0** Let me know, if that helps :)

Comment: now I realized, all the three functions from main.dart are not working when onPressed

Comment: See, this is how you pass a void function to another `StatefulWidget`. You can try doing `print()` inside you `play()`, and test it out in your `onPressed` @LinuMariya If the function is not working that means, you are doing something wrong inside your function, but passing it correctly via this code

Comment: Any kind of error you are getting while doing this OP @LinuMariya ?

Comment: it's not working. I think need to restructure the code

Comment: Yes< I believe @LinuMariya

Answer (score 0):

I think the other 2 gave you the rough idea of how to do it the way you want.
There is nothing wrong using those methods. They will work except when the navigation starts to get a little complex you will start using more pages and you might need to keep passing it down the tree.

So like easeccy mention look more into state management.
Things like [Blocs](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial), Redux are all very helpful.
Reason being just like how flutter builds things depending on setstate() the state management classes allows you to add the same event at different places as long as they are of the same instance. All the builders will rebuild based off the state they yield.

E.g. for Blocs if you were to add a play event to the bloc. no matter where you are as long as you are able to provide the bloc to the page you can add the event and anything that is on the screen (if you were to have multiple dart files building) will all be rebuilt depending on the state you will yield.

example of bloc
main.dart

```
void main() async{

  runApp(
    //Having this before return MaterialApp() ensures that you can call it 
    //anywhere in the app below this tree
    BlocProvider<TheTypeOfBloc>(
      create: (context) => TheTypeOfBloc(),
      child: App(),
  )

}
```

any other widgets/builds you have

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<TheTypeOfBloc,TheTypeOfState>(
     listener : (context,state){
     //tldr of listen =  when your state change do something.
     //so your void function can be call here
          if(state is playState){
             _play();
          }
     }
     child:BlocBuilder<TheTypeOfBloc,TheTypeOfState> (
    // basically anything below here gets rebuild when you change a state.
      builder: (context,state) {
         return //what you want to build here like listener based on the 
                //state or just build normally without the builder.
      }
     ),
    );
 }
```